# How to add a dataframe column based on two consecutive rows in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have column (A) in this pandas dataframe

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 7 |

Column (B) is created using the following formula:

> col B (2)= col A(1)+ col A(2)

How do I create column (B) from column A?

Comment: `df['B'] = df.A.rolling(min_periods=1, window=2).sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `shift()` to get the rows one row down and add it back to column `a`.

```py
df['b'] = df['a'] + df['a'].shift(fill_value=0)
```

[image: res]

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```py
df["B"] = df['A'] + df['A'].shift(1, fill_value= 0.)
```